# HTML Form -> Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

How would I submit an HTML Form to MySQL using PHP that I can then use a call reference to view the submissions at a later date? I want to make this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="upload.php" class="simple_form application" id="edit_application_52c5a2b3427a7d000200003f" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /></div>
<h2>Your Character</h2>
<p>Please enter your character's name and realm. We'll look up your details on the Armory.</p>
<div class="input string required"><label class="string required" for="application_character_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Character Name</label><div class="hint">The name of your character as it appears in game</div><input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="string required" id="application_character_name" name="application[character_name]" required="required" size="50" type="text"></div>
<div class="input string required"><label class="string required" for="application_character_realm"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Realm</label><div class="hint">The realm your character is currently on</div><input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="string required" id="application_character_realm" name="application[character_realm]" required="required" size="50" type="text"></div>
<div class="input select required"><label class="select required" for="application_character_class_id"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Class</label><div class="hint">Your character's class</div><select class="select required" id="application_character_class_id" name="application[character_class_id]"><option value="1">Warrior</option>
<option value="2">Paladin</option>
<option value="3">Hunter</option>
<option value="4">Rogue</option>
<option value="5">Priest</option>
<option value="6">Death Knight</option>
<option value="7">Shaman</option>
<option value="8">Mage</option>
<option value="9">Warlock</option>
<option value="10">Monk</option>
<option value="11">Druid</option></select></div>
<div class="input select required"><label class="select required" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_0_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Are you able to reliably make our progression raid schedule?</label><div class="hint">Main times are Tues-Saturday 8pm-12am Eastern, but progression will extend this greatly, including Sun, Mon, and longer hours.</div><select class="select required" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_0_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][0][answer]"><option value="No">No</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option></select></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_0_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000041" /><div class="input text required"><label class="text required" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_1_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> What spec/role(s) are you applying for? Are you comfortable playing multiple specs in a raid? </label><div class="hint">Do you have any alts that you raid on?</div><textarea class="text required" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_1_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][1][answer]" required="required" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_1_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][1][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000042" /><div class="input text required"><label class="text required" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_2_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> What is your guild and raiding history?</label><div class="hint">Include time spent and content cleared with each (specify 10/25) and reasons for leaving. Don&#x27;t bracket guild names.</div><textarea class="text required" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_2_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][2][answer]" required="required" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_2_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][2][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000043" /><div class="input text required"><label class="text required" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_3_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Why have you chosen to apply to The Elite Few?</label><div class="hint">Are you applying or plan to apply to any other guilds?</div><textarea class="text required" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_3_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][3][answer]" required="required" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_3_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][3][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000044" /><div class="input text required"><label class="text required" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_4_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Tell us about yourself!</label><div class="hint">Age, location, occupation/education focus, hobbies, etc.</div><textarea class="text required" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_4_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][4][answer]" required="required" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_4_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][4][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000045" /><div class="input text required"><label class="text required" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_5_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Please provide a UI screenshot taken in a raid.</label><div class="hint">Upload using a free service such as imgur.com. Bonus points for videos from your PoV raiding.</div><textarea class="text required" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_5_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][5][answer]" required="required" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_5_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][5][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000046" /><div class="input text required"><label class="text required" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_6_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Please provide a combat log link.</label><div class="hint">Such as Raid Logs, World of Logs, or Wow Meter Online. If you don&#x27;t have any from your guild, make a personal one in LFR DS.</div><textarea class="text required" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_6_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][6][answer]" required="required" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_6_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][6][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000047" /><div class="input text optional"><label class="text optional" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_7_answer"> Do you wish to include any additional contact information?</label><div class="hint">Phone Number, RealID, AIM, Skype, references, etc.</div><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_7_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][7][answer]" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_7_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][7][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000048" /><div class="input text optional"><label class="text optional" for="application_answered_questions_attributes_8_answer"> Is there anything else you would like to add?</label><div class="hint">Such as exceptional achievements in other games, video editing skills, addon development experience, etc.</div><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="application_answered_questions_attributes_8_answer" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][8][answer]" rows="4"></textarea></div>
<input id="application_answered_questions_attributes_8_id" name="application[answered_questions_attributes][8][id]" type="hidden" value="52c5a2b4427a7d0002000049" /><input id="application_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Into a HTML Form that has the responses stored in MySQL with a 2nd page that can connect to the database and view the submissions. This is my form URL:

> http://recruitment.elitefew.net/applications/new.html

if you need to reference anything.

Comment: so whats your question, post your form to a php script that inserts the data in to your database.

Comment: Look at some PHP tutorials dealing with databases.  That should help get you started in the correct directly.

Comment: read more about mysqli(connecting to database,insretion,....) [http://in2.php.net/mysqli](http://in2.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: thankyou very much, exactly what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

in the PHP file (upload.php in your case) you will get the entered data from the forms using $_POST["name"] where "name" is the name of the input. Then you have to do a MySQL insert. here is simple and good tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Also, a good practice is to avoid SQL injection. more info on that here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php